# Memory Limit of a Single Program and mmap

Tags: linux, memory

If one has a 32 bit machine, a single program cannot address more than 2^32 bytes, or 4 GB. Would making use of mmap() allow one to exceed the 4 GB limit?

Comment: [mmap()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) would allow you to implement [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

Comment: Right...but could you help me understand how that would help me find the answer? Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it implicit that this question is on virtual memory? All programs and OSes use virtual memory these days, right?

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is *yes.*  Did you have a more specific question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm still confused as to why you mentioned "Virtual Memory". Isn't the 4 GB I mentioned virtual memory as well? From what I understand the OS would be responsible for mapping the virtual memory (seen by the program) to RAM or swap.

Comment: Time to buy a 64 bits processor & machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can never exceed 4GiB of *simultaneously addressable* memory for a 32-bit binary. Usually, the kernel takes half and you are left with 2GiB user. Some kernels support a compromise split of 1GiB/3GiB.

However, you can ask the OS to map different portions of a file into memory at different times, essentially performing time multiplexing of the available address space. IMHO, at that point you might as well not memory map anything and just `read()` from the file into buffers.